# High Correlation between variables

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I am having trouble determining if " Can we predict the number of fires from the number of thefts"? By the correlation performed I can see that there is a correlation but its not very high because its 0.55. If it was higher I would conclude that there **IS A HIGH CORRELATION and YOU CAN PREDICT THE NUMBER OF FIRES FROM THE NUMBER OF THEFTS.** I am wrong ?

Comment: This is a statistics question, which is better to be posted on crossvalidated.  To answer your question, yes, you are wrong, because correlation doesn't mean causation. The high correlation between two variables $X$ and $Y$ doesn't mean there is a direct cause-effect relationship between $X$ and $Y$, since the correlation can be attributed to other lurking variables. The best you can do is trying to build a statistical model based on the collected data, and make conclusions accordingly (and to point UNCERTAINTY is crucial!)

Comment: @Solitary For forecasting, you don't necessarily need to take a stand on causation. We can estimate E[A | B] based on data. Maybe A causes B, B causes A, or C causes both. Who knows. And because we don't know causal structure, we can't say much about a counterfactual (eg. if we increase B, what happens to A? to answer that, we need to know causal structure). But just passive forecasting, yeah, you can do that: you have a estimated conditional expectation function

Comment: A okay thanks i will post it on their and thanks @Solitary

Answer (score 0):

You can use any correlation coefficient to predict values. $0.551$ is fine.

Comment: But in this problem could you say that the correlation can be used to predict the number of fires. Because since 0.551 is in between i am not too sure if to say it is a high correlation since its not high and not low

Comment: It doesnt matter. You can't say it's a high correlation, but it's not a bad one. People frequently use lower correlations

Comment: Ah okay because it was one of the questions i had for an assignment so we had to determine if we could use it or not. So in conclusion as long as the correlation is not negative it can be used to determine the number of fires in this case ?

Comment: You can always use the correlation